# Typescript: Typed list of keys to new Type Object

Tags: javascript, typescript, union-types

Have been given a typed object

```
type TestObj = {
    one: "up";
    two: "down";
    three: "left";
    four: "right";
}
```

Of which I have to choose 0 or more keys from and turn into an array

```
type TestObjKeys = keyof TestObj;
const chosen: TestObjKeys[] = ["one", "four"];
```

I need to convert this into a new typescript obj for only the keys that were chosen

```
type NewTestObj = Pick<TestObj, (typeof chosen)[number]>;
```

However the above gives me a type (equivalent to TestObj) for all keys, rather than use "one" and "four". I tried turning it into a const

```
const chosen2 = chosen as const;
```

But it errors out with

```
A 'const' assertions can only be applied to references to enum members, or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals.(1355)
```

How can I get only the chosen keys?

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwDyAjAVlAvFA3gKCkKgHsA7CALigCIBXMagbgKOAHdirqATYt0pi0LAAFgCcIlGgBsIAM2CCiUOcVpiuYgJYBzEYuYBfPKEiwEydAGkIIeFigBrW8TnnEqNMwDGZRFG8RYngIUio4D2tbeABtAF0HGOoyCGoAGhpVdWo4nz9gAKCQ0gAmB0Dg0KgAQ3tfUkQ8hoKK4oBmROTydMy1MRyauvzmU2gAOQg2CMsMbAAFLW9HAB5pzwyAClHXQsrSAEoY0loAWxQIMTiAPmYAelvRqAmpi08y%20cWVtfRN7bdW0IlQ7HM4Xa4jcDjSbfNAdD5LVavH5QLaQnYA0htYGnc6XG5AA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

1. Not put a type on `chosen`, so TypeScript can infer it. (You could use [`satisfies`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) to make sure it satisfies a type, though, if you wanted.)

   and
2. Use `as const` on the array you're assigning to `chosen`, so TypeScript knows it's a tuple of string literal types, not an array of string.

Like this:

```
const chosen = ["one", "four"] as const;
type NewTestObj = Pick<TestObj, (typeof chosen)[number]>;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwDyAjAVlAvFA3gKCkKgHsA7CALigCIBXMagbgKOAHdirqATYt0pi0LAAFgCcIlGgBsIAM2CCiUOcVpiuYgJYBzEYuYBfPKEiwEydAGkIIeFigBrW8TnnEqNMwDGZRFG8RYngIUgcAbWoyCGoAGhpVdWoAXSgAQ3tfUkRmU2gAOQg2OA90BwAFLW9HAB4SyzR4gAo81wCgkNIASnDSWgBbFAgxZIA+ZgB6CaIAPQB+IA)

(There's also no need for the `()` around `typeof chosen`, it has higher precedence [if that's the word] than the `[number]` after it. Just `typeof chosen[number]` will do the job.)

Answer (score 2):

`(typeof chosen)[number]` is just `TestObjKeys` not chosen keys.

If you add `as const` assertion to chosen directly, without the explicit type it would work.

```
const chosen = ["one", "four"] as const;
```

If you still need explicit type i recommend  using the [`satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator).

```
const chosen = ["one", "four"] as const satisfies TestObjKeys[];
```